# Generate barcode from PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe, barcode

Here’s what I’m trying to do. In my e-commerce store I need to print orders. On that PDF that is generated is an order #. I need to convert that number string into a scannable barcode that will then imbed itself onto that PDF next to the order number.

I have Adobe acrobat DC and it’s able to scan the document. I’m just at a loss for the next step.

The problem is that the shipping program that I use can only be connected to a 1d barcode scanner and rather than typing in either the order number or order name and then searching for the right one and opening it up manually I’m trying to simplify the search part.

Any idea on what to do?

Comment: Try asking on super user. Asking for tool recommendations is outside the scope of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of 1D-barcode symbologies around. Some of them do actually have a 1:1 relationship between the character and the symbol. That means, it is possible to represent the symbol directly by using an appropriate font.

Depending on the kind of characters you have to encode, you will chose the according symbology and font. You will also have to verify that your scanner can read the code (and the software understand it). Available as font, and easy to implement is for example Code39, which can display numbers and letters.

Comment: It’s not about the symbology. The problem I need a solution to is how to “pull” the order number, convert it to a 1d barcode, then add it to the pdf so that The order page can be printed with the barcode on it

Comment: You do have the order number, and you can print it. For the barcode, you take the same order number (plus maybe the control characters), and print it using the barcode font (this should work, unless you can not set the font for an individual text). If you can not get your hands on the order number in your order template, then it is not a PDF issue, but an issue of the ordering system and its order output template.